# Creating a semi-transparent version of a given Paint

Tags: java, javafx

Below, `B` is a semi-transparent version of color `A`. Both are derived from `s`.

```
String s = "1,2,3";
Paint A = Paint.valueOf("rgb(" + s + ")");
Paint B = Paint.valueOf("rgba(" + s + ",0.3)");
```

In the event that I have only `A` and not `s`, how can I create `B`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I would use Color instead of Paint here. Then you can do

```
Color a = Color.web("rgb(" + s + ")");
Color b = a.deriveColor(0, 1, 1, 0.3);
```

Comment: The problem is that `Paint A` is a given. So in the context of the question, I would do something like `Paint B = A instanceof Color ? ((Color)A).deriveColor(0,1,1,0.3) : null`?